# Apply map on *args in Python where *args are lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get a list of lists consisting of only 0 and 1 and map the first element of the first list with the first element of the second list and so on.

My mapping function is this:

```py
def intersect(*values):
    result = values[0]
    for idx in range(1, len(values)):
        result = result << 1
        result = result | values[idx]
    return result
```

I'm trying to do this but it does not work:

```py
def intersect_vectors(*vectors):
    return list(map(intersect, zip(vectors)))
```

It would work if I would knew the number of vectors and would have a function like this:

```py
def intersect_vectors(v1, v2, v3):
    return list(map(intersect, v1,v2,v3))
```

Example:
intersect_vectors([1,1],[1,0],[0,1]) would return [6,5] which is [b110, b101]

Comment: use `itertools.starmap`

Comment: Not sure about the rest, but i believe it should be `zip(*vectors)` to unpack and zip, else it will return unit length items

Comment: Just an aside, but where you are looping using `for idx in range(1, len(values)):` and the only thing that you are doing with `idx` is to index `values`, it would make more sense to do `for value in values[1:]:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explode your vectors with `*` and it will work the same:

```
def intersect_vectors(*vectors):
    return list(map(intersect, *vectors))
```

Comment: I did not know you can explode using *. It works, thanks!

Comment: @AlexandruAntochi Yes, this is also useful when you use `*args` in a wrapper function - combine using `*args` in the wrapper declaration and then explode using `*args` in the call to the wrapped function. Similarly `**kwargs`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is probably to delegate the functionality of transforming between a `list` and 'arguments' to a lambda:

```
return [list(map((lambda v: intersect(*v)), zip(vectors)))]
```